# Python/Odoo: ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d' does not match format '2020-10-09 00:00:0)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, odoo-13

I am beginner in odoo, while using following field getting error:

> ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d' does not match format '2020-10-09
> 00:00:0

Code of model file,

```
class PartnerImportUpdate(models.TransientModel):
_name = "partner.import.update"

import_update = fields.Selection(selection=[('import','Import'),('update','Update')],
                                           string="Import Operations",
                                           default="import")
# date = fields.Datetime("Date", default=lambda self: fields.datetime.now()) #commented
# date = fields.Date("Date",default=lambda *args: datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) #commented
date = fields.Date(string='Date',default=datetime.now())
one_time_import = fields.Boolean(string='First Time Import',help="If you have large no. of customers on your woocommerce  site then enable this It will import product page by page",default = False)
```

From fron-end getting following value:
[image: front-end]

(I am really a beginner and Basically I am just supposed to upgrade version of addon(multi-channel site))

Comment: Set the default value to `fields.Date.context_today`

Answer (score 0):

You problem is only because you create a date field and pass a date and time value.

To solve you problem only need remplace datetime.now() by date.today().

IMPORTANT!

You must import date from datetime

```
from datetime import date
```

MORE INFORMATION

For your information Odoo have two types of value for date

```
fields.Datetime()
```

And

```
fields.Date()
```

To help with date, Odoo create two variables to format date and datetime easier. Because date and datetime format could be different between two countries.

When you work on date with datetime.strftime. Never used own formatting but used DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT

```
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT
```